# How can I iterate through this array of arrays?

Tags: php

I want to get all the names of the three animals that is to say medor, felix and denver. Originally these data are from a mysql database and I'm creating a function to display all the animals' names.

**var_dump($tab)**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Médor' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Médor' (length=6)
      'species' => string 'chien' (length=5)
      2 => string 'chien' (length=5)
      'age' => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Félix' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Félix' (length=6)
      'species' => string 'chat' (length=4)
      2 => string 'chat' (length=4)
      'age' => string '97' (length=2)
      3 => string '97' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Denver' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Denver' (length=6)
      'species' => string 'dinosaure' (length=9)
      2 => string 'dinosaure' (length=9)
      'age' => string '65000000' (length=8)
      3 => string '65000000' (length=8)
```

I tried this but it begins with the indices of the first array and not the second

```
foreach($tab as $k => $val){
$tab[$k]["name"];
}
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop as follows to reference the elements you need (`$arr` is the source array):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo 'id : ' . $value['id'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'name: ' . $value['name'];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
id : 1
name: Médor
id : 2
name: Félix
id : 3
name: Denver
```

Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/D7mt7)